# URL keyword argument named "user". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am getting AssertionError in articledetails view. I am getting bellow error

```
AssertionError: Expected view ArticleDetailView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "user". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
```

I want to use RetrieveAPIView to Used for read-only endpoints to represent a single model instance.

Where I did wrong? And what is the correct way to fix this?
below is my *view.py* file

```
class ArticleDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):

    serializer_class = ArticleDetailSerial
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    lookup_field = 'user'
    queryset = ArticleDetail.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()  # here the object is retrieved
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)


    def get_object(self):
        """
        Returns the object the view is displaying.

        You may want to override this if you need to provide non-standard
        queryset lookups.  Eg if objects are referenced using multiple
        keyword arguments in the url conf.
        """
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        # Perform the lookup filtering.
        lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field

        assert lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs, (
                'Expected view %s to be called with a URL keyword argument '
                'named "%s". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` '
                'attribute on the view correctly.' %
                (self.__class__.__name__, lookup_url_kwarg)
        )

        filter_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]}
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)  # <-- can see that filtering is performed on the base of 'lookup_field'

        # May raise a permission denied
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

        return obj  # will return the single retrieved object
```

and this is my *url.py*

```
    path('details/', ArticleDetailView.as_view()),
    path('details/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view()),
```

Comment: remove `lookup_field` attribute from the view class

Comment: moreover, what have you gained from overriding those three methods? In a quick look, I couldn't found any differences with the original.